# How to limit Search Result to 1

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I am trying to limit the search results returned when doing a product search. The client wants to return only one option at a time. This is because their customers know the skus and dont want to see all the other skus that are similar.

By searching this way they will get an exact search. I found the `search_result.xml` file that if I update to 1 in the size I achieve my result.

The problem is I know not to edit inside the `vender/magento` files. How do a make this file to override it. Where do i begin as I am new to magento.

I understand how the theme files overwrite design things. However this is a backend thing. I would also like to add code that will show if no results are found to display something like we are currently out of stock.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured this out already, but why not redirect that search term to the specific product page? Go to Marketing>SEO and Search>Search Terms, find the appropriate Search Query and Click "Edit" in the "Action" column and enter a redirect URL to the appropriate product page.